# How to give transition effects according to viewport?

Tags: jquery, css, viewport

I want to add `animation` and `transition` effects when the page is scrolled and the viewport becomes visible on the screen. 
I tried the below one to check whether the specific block has come into viewport but it didn't work:

`js`

```
    (function($) {

  $.fn.visible = function(partial) {

      var $t            = $(this),
          $w            = $(window),
          viewTop       = $w.scrollTop(),
          viewBottom    = viewTop + $w.height(),
          _top          = $t.offset().top,
          _bottom       = _top + $t.height(),
          compareTop    = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
          compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

    return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));

  };

})(jQuery);

var win = $(window);

var allMods = $(".module");

allMods.each(function(i, el) {
  var el = $(el);
  if (el.visible(true)) {
    el.addClass("already-visible"); 
  } 
});

win.scroll(function(event) {

  allMods.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.addClass("come-in"); 
    } 
  });

});
```

`Html`

```
<section>

  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div> 
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>


</section>
```

`css`

```
   * {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  background: #eee;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.module {
  width: 48%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 4%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.module:nth-child(even) {
  margin-right: 0;
}



.come-in {
  transform: translateY(150px);
  animation: come-in 0.8s ease forwards;
}

.come-in:nth-child(odd) {
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

.already-visible {
  transform: translateY(0);
  animation: none;
}

@keyframes come-in {
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

Please help me with jquery to do that.

Comment: could you please post your HTML and CSS too?

Comment: I tried running your code and i can see the animation i.e. blocks coming up from bottom. What you think is not working properly?

Comment: when I scroll the page & the block is visible but the jquery is not working ie the transition effect is not getting applied. am using it in magento framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working. I have just increased the animation duration and its visible:

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.visible = function(partial) {

    var $t = $(this),
      $w = $(window),
      viewTop = $w.scrollTop(),
      viewBottom = viewTop + $w.height(),
      _top = $t.offset().top,
      _bottom = _top + $t.height(),
      compareTop = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
      compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

    return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));

  };

})(jQuery);

var win = $(window);

var allMods = $(".module");

allMods.each(function(i, el) {
  var el = $(el);
  if (el.visible(true)) {
    el.addClass("already-visible");
  }
});

win.scroll(function(event) {

  allMods.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.addClass("come-in");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
section {
  background: #eee;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.module {
  width: 48%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 4%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.module:nth-child(even) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.come-in {
  transform: translateY(150px);
  animation: come-in 1.8s ease forwards;
}
.come-in:nth-child(odd) {
  animation-duration: 1.6s;
}
.already-visible {
  transform: translateY(0);
  animation: none;
}
@keyframes come-in {
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>

  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>


</section>
```

Comment: hey its working now. I have misplaced the javascript in my framework. Thank you for the responce. I will upvote your answer.

Comment: oh...good catch...thanks @Ramya...the animation is fantastic...`:)`!

Comment: why should we use `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` ?

Comment: by above `<script>` tag we are loading the `jquery` `1.11.0` library onto our page. After that only our custom code will start executing correctly. Otherwise we will get error like `$` or `jQuery` is undefined.